# Set value within a word table cell as range

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing code to set the numerical value of a word table cell as a bookmark (and cross reference that bookmark later in the document). The issue I am having is that I can only set the cell itself as a range, which is causing formatting issues when I cross reference the boorkmark. I would rather bookmark the numerical value itself, as this does not result in a formatting issuse.

```
Dim BMRange As Word.Range  


Set BMRange = Activedocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).range


Activedocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="ExampleBookmark", Range:=BMRange 


Set BMRange = Activedocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 3).Range
BMRange .Collapse wdCollapseStart

BMRange.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Bookmark", ReferenceKind:= _
wdContentText, ReferenceItem:="ExampleBookmark", InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
```

Comment: Two problems, here: 1) A bookmark must have content in order to reference it; 2) there's a difference bookmarking a Cell.Range vs. bookmarking cell content. If you bookmark the cell Range, you get the cell structures; if the cell is "empty" when you set a bookmark INTO the cell, then it won't have any content when the user writes in the cell. Can you tell us more about the scenario how the user should work with the table / content?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go as follows:

```
Dim BMRange As Range
Dim tbl1 As Table

With ActiveDocument
    Set tbl1 = .Tables(1)
    Set BMRange = .Range(Start:=tbl1.Cell(2, 2).Range.Start, _
                         End:=tbl1.Cell(2, 2).Range.End)
    BMRange.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=-1
    .Bookmarks.Add name:="ExampleBookmark", Range:=BMRange
End With

With tbl1.Cell(2, 3).Range
    .Collapse (wdCollapseStart)
    .InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Bookmark", ReferenceKind:= _
                          wdContentText, ReferenceItem:="ExampleBookmark", InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
                          IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
End With
```

or, with a different stylistic choice:

```
Dim BMRange As Range

With ActiveDocument
    With .Tables(1)
        Set BMRange = .Parent.Range(Start:=.Cell(2, 2).Range.Start, _
                             End:=.Cell(2, 2).Range.End)
    End With

    BMRange.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=-1    
    .Bookmarks.Add name:="ExampleBookmark", Range:=BMRange

    With .Tables(1).Cell(2, 3).Range
        .Collapse (wdCollapseStart)
        .InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Bookmark", ReferenceKind:= _
                              wdContentText, ReferenceItem:="ExampleBookmark", InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
                              IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
    End With
End With
```

Comment: ConfusedDude, any feedback?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately the above code is giving me a type mismatch error

Answer (score 0):

When you bookmark any part of a table, you can reference numeric values in any cell in that table from elsewhere in the document using a formula field coded along the lines of:

{=Sum(Tbl B2)}

where 'Tbl' is the bookmark name and 'B2' is the cell reference.

As for what you're doing, you don't even need a bookmark, since it's in the same table. Simply use a formula field coded as:

{=B2}

You can do this programmatically thus:

```
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set Rng = .Tables(1).Cell(2, 3).Range
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="=B2", PreserveFormatting:=False
End With
```

**Note**: If you're creating the fields manually, the field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above examples must be created in the document itself via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> on a Mac); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In some instances I will need to reference cells in a different table, which is why I have looked at bookmarks.